# yii2 acf and rbac collaboration

Tags: yii2, advanced-custom-fields, rbac

Anyone know how to collaborate ACF and RBAC in yii2? i just want to add role name (ie: admin, contributors, editors) in my code:

```
'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => ['logout', 'signup', 'try','about'],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['try'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['?','admin','editors'],
                ],
             ],
]
```

Comment: Have you also the rbac module configurated and you are able to create permission ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create proper permission in your rbac module (the rbac rule are not mandatory) and the set in your acf the action allow or deny to the permission create .. then the user assigned to this premission or group of permissions can  accessing the action allowed ..

You can also test the permession for the user in you code

eg. assuming there is a set of users whit permissione manageUser you can test this way

```
  if (Yii::$app->User->can('manageUser')) {
         // your code for who ca manage user
  }
```

Comment: it means at every action i must write that code?
if (Yii::$app->User->can('manageUser')) {
        //the code
  }

Comment: No this is only if you want, inside specific action or funtion,  a different behavior for user permission .. For each action you should define the allow and the deny in ACF 'access' configuration  in related  controller